# Excel 2010 VBA creation date

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office, excel-2010

How to get the current workbook file creation date using VBA in excel 2010? I browsed all the properties of ThisWorkBook I don't seem to find something there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Creation Date")
'Output: 25.07.2011 14:51:11
```

This works for Excel 2003, don't have 2010 to test it.
Link to [MSDN Doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._workbook.builtindocumentproperties.aspx) for Office 2010, there is a list with other available properties on there, too.

Comment: Just perfect. Thank you man (I'll accept your answer in 9 minutes... SO said that :))

Comment: I would like to note that this does in fact give the Excel file creation date stored, but it turns out not to be useful. In absolutely all of my worksheets I'm looking at now, this is completely blank. You should look at the file creation date from the file system, instead.

Answer (score 4):

Use **[Scripting.FileSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hww8txat%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**

```
Dim oFS As Object
Dim creationDate As String

Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
creationDate = oFS.GetFile(ThisWorkbook.FullName).DateCreated
```

Comment: I found this solution but I was looking for a smoother way to do it like the one proposed by cularis. Thank you :)

Comment: You could also `filedatetime(ThisWorkbook.fullname)` for created|last mod

Comment: Alex your function gives the current time. It doesn't give the creation date. Thx, kind regards

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties.Item("Creation date").Value
```

To List all properties run this macro

```
Public Sub listProperties()
rw = 1
Worksheets(1).Activate
For Each p In ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties
    Cells(rw, 1).Value = p.Name
    On Error Resume Next
    Cells(rw, 2).Value = p.Value
    rw = rw + 1
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that FileDateTime works best.

```
FileDateTime (application.activeworkbook.path)
```

[Tech on the net](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/filedatetime.php) says it applies to 
Excel 2016, 2013, 2011 for Mac, 2010, 2007, 2003, XP, and 2000

[MSDN VBA 2010 - FileDateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/gg264782(v=office.14))